# Make polipo to log all urls

Tags: logs, http-proxy, polipo

i'm using polipo (proxy server) for local caching.

is there a way to log all access through polipo just like urlsnarf or other web server log file do?

```
logFile = "/tmp/access.log"
logLevel = ? # what should i fill to log all url?
```

and if possible, get cached file location also

output for 0xFF is something like this, it does not always show the requested url:

```
Couldn't parse last-modified: Sat, 23 Feb 2013 16:25:16 +0100
Uncacheable object http://nekovm.org/_media/neko-2.0.0.tar.gz (2120)
Superseding object: http://nekovm.org/_media/neko-2.0.0.tar.gz (200 425539 -1 (none) -> 200 425539 -1 (none))
Unsupported Cache-Control directive post-check -- ignored.
Unsupported Cache-Control directive pre-check -- ignored.
Couldn't parse last-modified: Sat, 23 Feb 2013 16:25:16 +0100
Uncacheable object http://nekovm.org/_media/neko-2.0.0.tar.gz (2120)
Superseding object: http://nekovm.org/_media/neko-2.0.0.tar.gz (200 425539 -1 (none) -> 200 425539 -1 (none))
Vary header present (Accept-Encoding).
Vary header present (Accept-Encoding).
Vary header present (Accept-Encoding).
Superseding object: http://opalrb.org/opal-parser.js (206 709851 1363984598 (none) -> 206 709851 1363984598 (none))
Vary header present (Accept-Encoding).
Superseding object: http://opalrb.org/opal-parser.js (200 709851 1363984598 (none) -> 200 709851 1363984598 (none))
Vary header present (Accept-Encoding).
Superseding object: http://opalrb.org/opal-parser.js (200 709851 1363984598 (none) -> 200 709851 1363984598 (none))
Vary header present (Accept-Encoding).
Superseding object: http://opalrb.org/opal-parser.js (200 709851 1363984598 (none) -> 200 709851 1363984598 (none))
Vary header present (Accept-Encoding).
Superseding object: http://opalrb.org/opal-parser.js (200 709851 1363984598 (none) -> 200 709851 1363984598 (none))
Vary header present (Accept-Encoding).
Vary header present (Accept-Encoding).
Vary header present (Accept-Encoding).
Uncacheable object http://www.youtube.com/?hl=en&gl=US (2050)
```

Comment: have you tried `logLevel=0xFF` ? I just found in google search

Comment: yes i have, but it still doesn't always show the requested urls

Comment: Do you want to trace log only for testing purpose ?

Comment: for logging purpose :3

Comment: would you  like to try different proxy server ?

Comment: I had work with proxy i.e `safesquid` , it has many log level you can check this link http://www.safesquid.com/book/export/html/255

Answer (score 3):

To enable logging, the [manual](http://www.pps.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~jch/software/polipo/polipo.html#Logging) states that:

> 2.1.3 Logging
>
> When it encounters a difficulty, Polipo will print a friendly message.
>   The location where these messages go is controlled by the
>   configuration variables **logFile** and **logSyslog**. If logSyslog is true,
>   error messages go to the system log facility given by logFacility. If
>   logFile is set, it is the name of a file where all output will
>   accumulate. If logSyslog is false and logFile is empty, messages go to
>   the error output of the process (normally the terminal).
>
> The variable logFile defaults to empty if daemonise is false, and to
>   ‘/var/log/polipo’ otherwise. The variable logSyslog defaults to false,
>   and logFacility defaults to ‘user’.
>
> If logFile is set, then the variable logFilePermissions controls the
>   Unix permissions with which the log file will be created if it doesn’t
>   exist. It defaults to 0640.
>
> **The amount of logging is controlled by the variable logLevel. Please
>   see the file ‘log.h’ in the Polipo sources for the possible values of
>   logLevel.**
>
> Keeping extensive logs on your users browsing habits is probably a
>   serere violation of their privacy. If the variable scrubLogs is set,
>   then Polipo will scrub most, if not all, private information from its
>   logs.

Following on from that, log.h (from [here](https://github.com/gorakhargosh/polipo/blob/master/log.h#L23)) has the following levels:

```
#define L_ERROR 0x1
#define L_WARN 0x2
#define L_INFO 0x4
#define L_FORBIDDEN 0x8
#define L_UNCACHEABLE 0x10
#define L_SUPERSEDED 0x20
#define L_VARY 0x40
#define L_TUNNEL 0x80
#define LOGGING_DEFAULT (L_ERROR | L_WARN | L_INFO)
#define LOGGING_MAX 0xFF
```

So, for example, if you wanted to see all of the log messages in a file, the recommended configuation is (in `/etc/polipo/config`):

```
  logFile=/var/log/polipo
  logLevel=4
```

Answer (score 2):

As per `polipo -v`  Max `Loglevel` is `0xFF`

```
logLevel integer 0x7 Logging level (max = 0xFF)
```

Reference [Link](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=209833)

Answer (score 1):

The location where the logs go is controlled by the **configuration variables** `logFile` and `logSyslog`. If logSyslog is true, error messages go to the **system log** facility given by logFacility. If logFile is set, it is the **name of a file** where all output will accumulate. If logSyslog is false and logFile is empty, messages go to the error output of the process (normally the terminal).
The variable logFile defaults to empty if **daemonise** is false, and to `/var/log/polipo`
otherwise. The variable logSyslog defaults to false, and logFacility defaults to `user`.
The amount of logging is controlled by the variable `logLevel`. Please see the file `log.h` in
the Polipo sources for the possible values of **logLevel**.

solved?